# Inclusion in all $L^p$ spaces

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

If you can show that a random variable is in every $L^p$-space for a given measure, for every $1<p<\infty$ then can you deduce that it is also in $L^1$?

Comment: If you're on a finite measure space it's true, and in fact it's enough to just have it in some $L^p$. This is by Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. If $\mu$ is a finite postive measure and $f\in L^2(\mu),$ then

$$\int_X|f|\,d\mu = \int_X|f|\cdot 1\,d\mu \le (\int_X|f|^2\,d\mu)^{1/2}\cdot (\int_X 1^2\,d\mu)^{1/2}$$ $$ = (\int_X|f|^2\,d\mu)^{1/2}\cdot \mu(X)^{1/2} < \infty.$$

Comment: By a similiar argument, if $1\leq p \leq q$ then $f\in L^q(\mu) \implies f\in L^p(\mu) $. Of course, we assume that we are working on a probability space

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks :)  This is a wonderful point!

Comment: There's another approach, which is more elementary. Suppose $f\in L^p,$ for some $p>1.$ Then

$$\int_X|f|\,d\mu = \int_{|f|<1}|f|\,d\mu  +\int_{|f|\ge 1}|f|\,d\mu \le \mu(X) + \int_{|f|\ge 1}|f|^p\,d\mu <\infty.$$

Comment: Nice & very straight forward (both) :)